# Joomla plugin install file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible in joomla `install.xml` file write some sql, which would be executed on install? Or somehow else do this trick? The point is that i have written custom authorization plug-and i have to disable/replace/delete an existing one.

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=574026 This should help you. But I think the answer is no unfortunately!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use external SQL-files and make them execute on install.

1. Create a SQL-file *install.mysql.utf8.sql* in your plugin root with some content like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__tablename` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

2. In your XML-manifest add the file as a *filename* node underneath *files*:

```xml
<files>
    <filename>install.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
</files>
```

3. Add a [install node](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#SQL) in your manifest that tells Joomla what SQL file to execute on installation:

```xml
<install>
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
```

If you install the plugin with this and it's a **new installation** (the plugin havn't been installed on the site before) then Joomla will execute the SQL-file.

If you need to execute SQL on a upgrade (reinstallation) of the plugin you'd have to use the [update](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Update_of_the_SQL_schema) node.

An alternative to SQL-files is to use PHP-scripts to be executed (which can run SQL queries themselves) on install/update. For help with that, see [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Script_file).

Comment: Is it possible to do UPDATE sql?