# Is it possible for a Joomla Form plugin to create a table and save form data to that table?

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, joomla

I am working on creating a Joomla based web service that is easy to use. The end goal is to allow customers the ability to manage the site from the front-end with no back-end (administrator) access. To accomplish this task I am using K2 that has existing front-end editing. Then behind the scenes we will provide technical support. Essentially, non-techy customers can easily manage their site, with us managing the tech side of things.

I need to provide a few forms (Contact, Event registration/payment and Donation payment). These forms also require that certain aspects of the forms can be updated via the front-end leveraging K2. (eg. The email address to send form submissions to.) With most forms components this can be done easily from the admin panel, however this is too complicated for non-techy customers and means we would have to provide admin access instead of just front-end. Not a good solution.

I have created a K2 contact Form plugin that will allow a customer to update where the email is sent on submission, when logged into the front-end with correct permissions. So far so good. I chose a plugin to accomplish this so we could leverage the existing front-end editing.

The issue I ran into is how to make my plugin create a table, preferably on install, as well as save form data to that table on successful submission. I'm not sure that this is possible using a plugin and have not found any documentation or sources mentioning how to accomplish this task.

I was hoping someone may be able to confirm either way if this is possible? Any suggestions, comments, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=joomla+plugin+create+table

Answer (score 0):

While installing plugin you can create `DB` tables, Its not a big deal create the `SQL` file with proper table query and set that inside your `XML` file.

Also you can create a forms(with many fields) inside your plugin file, But the problem is you should have any components controller and model related to this form submission task. Bcoz form submission you cannot handle inside plugin file, it should required a `controller` and `model` files.

So basically your plugin have related components then you can achieve it with form action like below.

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=your_controller.your_function">
```

For creating DB table while installing plugin check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743765/joomla-plugin-install-file)

Hope its helps..